# If a program has #include <abc/xyz.h>, where is the directory abc located?

Tags: include-path

When I run the program, I get the message:

error: abc/xyz.h: No such file or directory.

abc resides in the same directory as the C code of the program I am trying to run.

Comment: How are you "running" (I'm assuming you mean compiling)? GCC from the command-line, an IDE, makefile?

Answer (score 2):

The location to find headers is an implementation-defined thing, both for the `<>` and `""` variants.

So, it depends on which actual implementation you're using.

---

The relevant bits of C99 are from 6.10.2, "Source file inclusion" (unchanged in C11), quoted below.

A preprocessing directive of the form

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
```

searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

A preprocessing directive of the form

```
# include "q-char-sequence" new-line
```

causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
```

with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.

---

Many implementations will search the current directory for include files so, if your file is actually `<current-directory>/abc/include/libsomething/xyz.h`, you would use:

```
#include "abc/include/libsomething/xyz.h"
```

Alternatively, you could configure the compiler to modify the search paths, such as with `gcc -Iabc/include/libsomething` and just use:

```
#include "xyz.h"
```

Personally, I prefer the full specification since it makes conflicts less likely (you may have a *different* `xyz.h` somewhere else on the include-file search path).

Comment: h-char-sequence = abc/xyz.h in the C code I am trying to run/compile. However, the file xyz.h is not in the directory abc, it is in a directory 2 levels below abc - i.e., the correct path is abc/include/lib<softwarename>/xyz.h. Is that a problem?

Comment: @LinuxUser, it almost certainly _is_ a problem :-) If your implementation searches the current directory, then you should be using the full relative path. Alternatively, if you can use someething in the compiler command line to modify the search path (such as `gcc -I`), you can just use the headr file name without a path.

Comment: It seems to me, from your explanation @paxdiable, that #include <...> and #include "..." work pretty much the same way? I created many symbolic links so that the program finds whatever it wants in the headers exactly where it wants it, but it still complains about not being able to find the header files. So, if the program is present in directory /src, and wants /gsl/gsl_matrix.h, I have created a symbolic link in src to the gsl directory. However, the program still complains about not being able to find some .h files in the /gsl directory.

Comment: @LinuxUser, no, not exactly the same. While both are implementation defined in where they search, that doesn't mean they search exactly the same locations. For example, `<>` may not necessarily search the current directory. The quote variant will fall back to the `<>` variant if the header is not found using the `""` path.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo . Do you have any insight on why I can't run my program? I have gsl in /MyPackage/include/gsl. I am trying to compile a header file in /MyPackage/src. It has a header that has lines like #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>, etc. The Makefile has the line INCLUDE = -I/MyPackage/include. Why then do I get errors of this kind: MyHeaderFile.h:19:28: error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory ?

Comment: Is there any way to track what the Makefile does, so that I can determine where it fails? What is the INCLUDE and LIBS paths, for example?

Comment: @LinuxUser, it's not enough to set INCLUDE, you need to ensure you _use_ that in the compiler command, like `gcc $(INCLUDE) ...`. As to tracing make,  you can run any command in your rules, such as `echo $(LIB)`. Some also show lots of debug info if you use `make -d`, for example.